# Oracle SQL - How to show NULL ROWS

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count the number of delays between days 16000 and 16005. The problem is that I only obtain rows for days where there have been delays. If the query detects a day with zero delays I don't get that day showing up. I want ALL DAYS showing up, even if there haven't been any delays. I thought I would solve this using a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a table which contains all days between 16000 and 16005 indepently of the number of delays, but it doesn't make a difference.

How can I achieve this? It seems fairly simple but I can't get my head around this. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT A.dep_date, COUNT(A.leg) AS x

FROM delay A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT utilization.date
FROM utilization
GROUP BY utilization.date
HAVING utilization.date BETWEEN 16000 AND 16005) B
ON B.date = A.dep_date

GROUP BY A.dep_date

HAVING A.dep_date BETWEEN 16000 AND 16005

ORDER BY A.dep_date
```

Comment: Your driving off of the `delay` table that's why you only see those rows. Try a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or switch the driving table to the `utilization` table and `LEFT JOIN` on the `delay` table.

Answer (score 0):

You are still only seeing days with a delay because you are only returning rows contained within 'A' in your HAVING.

Try something like this

```
SELECT
    u.date,
    a.cnt AS x
FROM
    utilization u
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    dep_date,
    count(leg) as cnt
 from
    delay
 group by
    dep_date) a
ON u.date = A.dep_date
WHERE u.date BETWEEN 16000 AND 16005
ORDER BY u.date
```

(not tested)

You might find better performance by adding a date range into the sub-query. Depends on how much data you have if it's worth it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mathew. I tried your code but didn't work. In any case, you've showed me what I was doing wrong, which gave me the idea of using UNION and SUM. I finally got the result I was looking for.

```
SELECT date, SUM(x) as y
FROM

(
SELECT B.date, 0 AS x
FROM utilization B
WHERE B.date BETWEEN 16000 AND 16005
GROUP BY B.date

UNION

SELECT A.dep_date, COUNT(A.leg) AS x
FROM delay A
WHERE A.dep_date BETWEEN 16000 AND 16005
GROUP BY A.dep_date
)

GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```